# How to stretch Grid within a Viewbox

Tags: .net, xaml, grid, viewbox

I would like to stretch  `Grid` within a `Viewbox`. The code I have god does not work properly. Any clue?

```
 <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

[image]

Comment: Add Stretch="Fill" in ViewBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change strech property of Viewbox to Fill like below.

< Viewbox  Stretch="Fill" >

Answer (score 4):

You want the [ViewBox property Stretch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.